# How to programmatically detect restricted mobile data?

Tags: android, connection, mobile-data

In some devices(device may or may not be rooted device) we have an option for restricting wifi and mobile data.
How can I check programmatically the device restricted internet connection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Any Application Background data Usage Status in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802374/how-to-get-any-application-background-data-usage-status-in-android)

Comment: @JakubGabčo you're right if he wants exactly the status. this is only possible with root access. however the online check is possible as you can see in my answer

Comment: @Jakub Gabčo thanks for your input but in my case device may or may not be rooted, what am looking for a common solution.

Comment: Impossible unrooted

Answer (score -2):

Out of my utils class:

```
    /**
     * Check if the device is connected to the internet.
     *
     * @param context the application context
     * @return boolean if device is online
     */
    public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

> `ConnectivityManager` is supposed to report null when you are not allowed to do work in the background or are not allowed to connect to the internet.

Comment: This method will return boolean based on internet ON or OFF. I want to programmatically detect internet restricted is enabled or not.

Comment: @Sanal Impossible without root & duplicate